# Python UDP IPv6 Server does not receive packet, though seen by Wireshark

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I've got a device (address bbbb::17:d00:30:76fb) that sends a periodic packet to my laptop, Windows 10, address 2a02:2c40:100:a001:919a:2a07:1a4d:d8bc with dst_port 61624, packet len 8.

This packet clearly arrives on the laptop, as seen by Wireshark.

```
332 28.379668   bbbb::17:d00:30:76fb    2a02:2c40:100:a001:919a:2a07:1a4d:d8bc  UDP 70  61624 → 61624 Len=8
```

My laptop is running the following Python script (ignore the stuff about srvIds):

```
import socket
import sys

NODE_ADDRESS = "bbbb::17:d00:30:76fb"
# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('', 61624)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)
numb = 1

while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print('received {} bytes from {}'.format(
        len(data), address))
    print(data)
    srvIdFrom =  data[-4] | data[-3] << 8
    srvIdTo =  data[-2] | data[-1] << 8
    print('packet had srvIdFrom {} and srvIdTo {}'.format(srvIdFrom,srvIdTo))
    numb = numb + 1
    if numb > 120:
        numb = 1
    if data:
        my_bytes = bytearray()

        dummySrvId = 98
        my_bytes.append(numb)
        my_bytes.append(dummySrvId & 0xff)  # -4 (offset from end)
        my_bytes.append(dummySrvId >> 8)    # -3
        my_bytes.append(srvIdFrom & 0xff)   # -2
        my_bytes.append(srvIdFrom >> 8)     # -1


        #addressTo = (address[0],61624) # reply back, depends on how it is received
        addressTo = (NODE_ADDRESS, 61624) #reply to direct node
        sent = sock.sendto(my_bytes, addressTo)

        #print('sent {} bytes {} back to {} with numb {}'.format(
        #    sent, my_bytes, addressTo,numb))
        srvIdFrom =  my_bytes[-4] | my_bytes[-3] << 8
        srvIdTo = my_bytes[-2] | my_bytes[-1] << 8
        print('return packet had srvIdFrom {} and srvIdTo {}'.format(srvIdFrom,srvIdTo))
```

While running this script, it however never gets past:

```
starting up on  port 61624

waiting to receive message
```

So I am receiving a packet, but the server never consumes it. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to bind to `'::'` instead of just `''`

Comment: Did this, no cigar.

Comment: I am beyond retarded. The IPv6 address had a subtle mistake, once fixed, this works!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am beyond retarded. The IPv6 address had a subtle mistake, once fixed, this works!